# Camunda BPM - Spring compatibility

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, bpmn, camunda-plugin

I'm trying to migrate application with Camunda BPM 7.14.0 and Spring Boot 2.7.2 dependencies to latest Spring version(3.0.1/3.0.2) and at least Camunda 7.16.

Unfortunately I'm receiving some errors during migration and would like to ask what is the compatible version of Camunda which I can use with Spring 3.0.1?

From the compatibility matrix I can read that Camunda 7.18 is compatible only with version 2.7.x
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/version-compatibility/
Can someone confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm that 7.18 is compatible with 2.7.x

Spring Boot 3.0 requires some change in the autoconfiguration declaration and as far as I understood, the community edition [will not support](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/issues/2755#issuecomment-1354850165) it until 7.20.0.

But the same thread mentions [a manual fix](https://gist.github.com/edudant/66cd658ba54439c9052681a0d84d66a9) that I haven't tried so far.